# How many clock cycles to modify C++11 atomic bool?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, concurrency, atomic

I was wondering how many clock cycles should it takes to modify a std::atomic (or atomic_flag) assuming it is using the strictest memory model setting?

Comment: You are missing a lot of crucial information: What processor (architecture, model, type),  where is the data at the time you are modifying it (cache, main memory, cache of another processor), how many other processors are there in the system, and how many of those processors hold a copy of the atomic variable?

Comment: Say Linux Ubuntu 12.04, 2.5 GHz, and Intel 64 bit architecture. I suppose the scenario I care about is that the value is already in L1 cache. Then there are two further cases: 1) no other threads running, and 2) multiple threads accessing the variable but for simplicity let's say there's just a producer and consumer (bound on different cores).

Comment: Somewhere between a few dozen and thousands... Is that not a good enough answer?

Comment: It's somewhat of a silly question, the answer being: between 0.5 and 1,000,000 cycles, depending on whether a) the implementation is lockfree or not b) whether there is congestion, and c) whether there is a data dependency. IF it's a lockfree implementaion in absence of congestion and data dependency, it runs at the speed the CPU can start a new integer instruction (typically 2-4 per clock). With data dependency, it's around 20 cycles (or 3-5 times more on different cores on a NUMA system). Otherwise, with congestion or locks, it takes... any... amount of cycles.

Comment: Well I imagine the atomic variable is lock-free and should be executed immediately when the active thread gets to it.

Comment: I just did some timings and the median time to modify the atomic bool on my setup is 35 nanoseconds. This is much longer than modifying a simple variable.

Comment: @NateDoromal: Yes, I expect that it IS indeed much worse than updating a normal variable. Because the CPU has to do a lot more work. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite hard to determine exactly how many clockcycles it actually takes. I will, instead, try to explain what actually happens, if we assume it's an x86 processor (as stated in the comment), and the runtime library implements the `atomic` using "locked" instructions - if any of these assumptions are false, then "all bets are off" as the saying goes:

When performing a `atomic` operation, the CPU will first ensure it has "exclusive" access to the (potentially) cached value. This means sending a message to all other CPU's saying "I'm *it* for this variable". Each of the other CPU's then has to flush its copy (if modified) and mark the value as "invalid", and then reply with "I'm done".

Once all processors have said "I'm done", the main processor can continue. This process, especially in a large system with lots of CPU(cores) can take quite some time (hundreds or thousands of cycles).

Of course, the CPU can optimise this by knowing that no other CPU has read this value, or that no other CPU has issued a write for this value, in which case, it can be really quick.

You can perhaps get an idea of how bad this is [on a particular machine] by writing some code where you, in two threads, loop around for, say, 1 second, trying to update and read the same atomic variable, and see how good/bad it is. Then try two "update" loops (so you make updates between two threads).

Answer (score 1):

It is about the same as an access to uncached main memory.  In the order of 100-1000 ns, or about 100 clock cycles.